# How to keep wheel ramps from sliding?

Tags: tools, safety

I have a very smooth garage floor. When I try to use my wheel ramps for the quick and easy way to raise a vehicle, they will often slide, sometimes just one, but other times both. They will sometimes even continue to slide as the tire pushes them forward. What is an easy/safe way to keep them from sliding?

[image]

Comment: put her in 4WD (^_^)

Comment: @RozzA - It still pushed the ramp out from under it, though helped slightly.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has suggested having someone else hold them in place.

Comment: Those ramps are death traps. I make mine out of 2x8's....http://www.instructables.com/id/Ramps-for-a-Low-Car/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Duct Tape. Of course.

Take a piece of duct tape and tape it to the lip of the ramp. Run it out 12 inches/30cm and then fold it over and run it back to the ramp. Stick this on the backside of the ramp.

As you roll up on the ramp, the tape will be trapped underneath your tire and the ramp will be unable to slide away.

[image: Hastily drawn illustration]

Comment: There is a use for Duct tape *everywhere*. Thanks for the great answer :o)

Answer (score 13):

Use an old towel underneath the ramp, such that your vehicle runs onto the towel first

`ramp`
|¯¯¯\
|____\  `towel` O`wheel`
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

This is possibly the cheapest, simplest & least destructive method (as long as you don't mind your towel maybe getting small holes in it.)
Old towels make the best general purpose rags.

**edit:** if the towel still slips once the front wheel leaves the ground, you need more length, you could use a cargo strap (if you have one) instead of a towel - hook it around the ramp, then lay the strap down and drive onto it fully so it's pinched under the back wheel

Comment: This is a great idea! And simple to boot

Comment: i use old towels for keeping my hydrolic jack wrapped in as well - protection, non-slip, somewhere to wipe your hands, if doing work in the dirt you can lie on it, etc.

Comment: Especially +1 for the ASCII art :)

Comment: I've just realised the towels might slide as well, once the wheel is up on the ramp and the ramp cuts thru the towel... :(

Comment: @Rozza you can fix the cutting issue with tubing.  When dealing with a hard metal edge you can blunt and soften it with a  tube that is cut lengthwise so it's end looks like a `c`.  You press the metal edge into the opening left by the cut.  You'll find the same trick being used on the edges of some car doors.  Keeps you from dinging your neighbors paint when you park and open the door to wide.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I'd especially want tubing or similar if using the cargo strap mentioned in the edit. Don't want those fail later.

Comment: Instead of a towel, I use a yoga mat. I bought them for about 4$ a piece. They're made to be sticky.

Answer (score 11):

**Threaded Inserts in your concrete**

I have placed various [threaded interference inserts](https://www.google.com/search?q=cement%20threaded%20insert&oq=cement%20threaded%20insert&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.4730j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) in my garage/shop floor.  I've put them in locations where they will be useful to tie down a motorcycle or to have a bolt just sticking out of the cement to prevent something like this from sliding.

I've used various diameters of insert.

I can use them for a variety of situations.

- Motorcycle Tie Down
- Bolt down a ramp
- Bench Mount
- Hold a transmission jack into place
- insert task here.

They've proven to one of the most useful things in my little shop.  I can just move a device and if it requires a little better of a mounting solution, I have it already.

Of course you have to be OK with drilling holes in your slab, which I am.

Comment: The nice thing about this solution is that it doesn't even have to be a threaded insert. A drilled hole and dowel pin should be sufficient to prevent the ramp from sliding about

Answer (score 8):

One way would be to use the non-slip padding they make for kitchen shelves. Put a square of that down, and put a slightly smaller 3/4in plywood square on top of it. Then the ramp on top of the plywood. The rubber sheet prevents the slide, and the feet of the ramp dig just enough in the wood to prevent it from moving.

Comment: Possible alternative to the non-slip padding: old bicycle tubes. I haven't used them for this, but they do tend to work for keeping accessories from slipping on my bike handlebars, so I'm inclined to think it'll work. (My plastic car ramps already have rubber under the tip of the wedge.)

Answer (score 7):

I put a long enough 2X4 behind both ramps and then two to three cinder blocks behind the wood to keep it from moving. You can substitute the cinder blocks for anything else that's heavy (but don't have your mother in law stand in because then she won't shut up about it). ;)

```
|block|       |block|        |block|
---------------2X4------------------
 |ramp|                      |ramp|
```

Comment: I take it the Mo-N-Law comment was thrown in from experience?

Comment: I can neither confirm or deny that my mother in law is heavy and won't shut up about anything. ;-)

Comment: @racefever  I have the same one over here.  Duct tape and a sock are recommended solution.  I read it on the internet.    +1 for that.

Comment: Mine can chew through duct tape...

Answer (score 6):

You can fasten wooden stoppers to the floor with concrete bolts.

Alternatively, you could notch your floor in a specific area for where you would use your stands.

You could get a friend to hold the stands in place with a piece of wood as well.

If none of these are an option for you, as long as you have a steady wall or object in front of the stands, you can create a "deadman". Obtain sturdy pieces of wood and run it from the wall/object to the stands to prevent them from moving.